# Resigned .apk not installing in android

Tags: android

I am trying to manually add text file into assets folder of .apk using `aapt tool` or can able to add any `ZIP reader`. After adding text file I resigned .apk by using `jarsigner` and aligned it using `zipalign`.

Here problem is, that the final .apk   is not getting installed on my device.

I referred these posts but they didn't help

[Can I resign an .apk with a different certificate than what it came with?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3267216/can-i-resign-an-apk-with-a-different-certificate-than-what-it-came-with)

[Repackage APK file to contain custom assets - what build tool to use?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4793220/repackage-apk-file-to-contain-custom-assets-what-build-tool-to-use?rq=1)

[Android: How to manually add a file to apk?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3535728/android-how-to-manually-add-a-file-to-apk)

**SOLUTION:**
 [This helps to fix my issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5505240/trying-to-manually-sign-android-package-with-jarsigner-exe-and-install-with-adb)

Device shows `Application not installed` error

Comment: is there any already installed version of the same app in the device./

Comment: No I uninstalled that app

Comment: clean the project and  build new apk please ensure  you have sufficient memory to instal the app

Comment: @Sreekanthss if I am installing .apk directly means it working fine but I am adding text file into assets folder using `aapt tool` that time only facing issue like this.

Comment: how you unsigned you apk, is it correct ?

Comment: @Sreekanthss getting unsigned apk from eclipse only by doing `Export unsigned apk`

Comment: can you able to try with the "AppInstaller"

Comment: no but why i need to use AppInstaller

Comment: http://developer.android.com/tools/publishing/app-signing.html

Comment: All applications must be signed. The system will not install an application on an emulator or a device if it is not signed.

Comment: Yeah I know that here I am using signed apk only

Comment: Resigned/unsigned  .apk is your question right

Comment: Yeah, here I am not speaking about normal apk releasing from eclipse. I am altering that apk then only I am getting issue.

Comment: so it is not singed, please use that AppInstaller and try

Answer (score 0):

if one application with special package name has been installed on your device, the next instance of that can be installed, only if both of them has the same signature.
so if you want to do that, you must remove the previous one, or you must change package name.

Comment: it is working fine while installing directly, issue comiong only when i using `aapt tool` to add text file into assets.

Comment: have you looked at [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7360149/how-to-modify-a-pre-packaged-apk-file-on-client-side-by-user-who-is-using-my-des)

Comment: yeah i already looked on it but i did not tried it because i did not understand step 3 & 4. Do you have any idea on steps 3&4.